# Parse postgres object literals

Tags: java, postgresql, ebean

I'm working on a java/postgres project, and one of the db tables contains a fairly complex composite type. The project uses Ebean for O/R mapping, and I'm trying to map an ebean class to the table in question. After a bit of digging, I came to the conclusion that I basically have two options available:

1. customize the way Ebean uses the database to populate/persist the type (something similar to hibernate's UserType), but I haven't yet found a way to do that in Ebean
2. transfer the data to/from the database as text using Postgres' object literal notation, but I'm having trouble implementing a parser and serializer for that notation because I can't find a specification for it - postgres documentation only touches the subject briefly with a few examples

Am I missing something, or is this simply not doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Object literals are basically:

```
 (csv-data)
```

Array literals are basically:

```
 {csv-data}
```

So basically you can use csv generation routines and surround them with parentheses or brackets... On the other side you can strip these out and then use a csv parser to pull the data back.  The CSV can be appropriately nested as well, and double quoting rules apply.

I have not done this in Java but I am doing it in Perl.